# Table Sorter Filter - change reset filter value

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is there a way to change the reset filter value from blank to something else? i.e. "All"

Saw this JSfiddle from mottie that uses data-value, but what it does is it sets it as the default filter value.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1005/

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="filter-select">Name</th>
      <th>Major</th>
      <th data-value="f">Sex</th>
      <th>English</th>
      <th>Japanese</th>11
      <th>Calculus</th>
      <th>Geometry</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

What I need is a reset filter value that will show all values when selected just like when the blank value is selected on a column that has a filter-select attribute.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering a `filterReset` method, set your desired default filters ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1086/)):

```
$(function() {
  var $table = $('#mytable');
  $('#reset-link').click(function(e) {
    $table.trigger('sortReset', function() {
      $.tablesorter.setFilters($table, ['', '', 'f']);
    });
    return false;
  });
  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
    widgets: ['filter', 'zebra']
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey @mottie, didn't quite get your answer. But what I basically need is to change the blank value on a column with a "filter-select" attribute to "All" in which does the same thing, shows all of the values on that column.

Comment: I got the answer,  I used - "data-placeholder" attribute to update the blank value to "All"

<th class="filter-select" data-placeholder="All">Sex</th>